# How do I insert externally-generated images into R markdown programatically?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Instead of having to include the relative path to an image like so:

```
![\label{fig:R1amb}R1 Ambient RNA Contamination](../outs/pre-processing/ambientRNA_R1.png)
```

I would like to bring in an image from the yaml object like so:

```
![\label{fig:R1amb}R1 Ambient RNA Contamination](`r yaml$inputs$R1_ambient`)
```

where `yaml$inputs$R1_ambient` contains the full path to the `png`. However, this does not render the image. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which flavour of Rmarkdown you're using (so not sure about `yaml$inputs` and the label cross-reference). However, my solution should work nevertheless.

You can use `knitr::include_graphics` in an `R` chunk to make use of the parameterised path:

````
---
title: "Test"
date: "4/4/2022"
output: html_document
params:
  R1_ambient: "test.png"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Plot
```{r R1amb, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "R1 Ambient RNA Contamination"}
knitr::include_graphics(params$R1_ambient)
```
````

Comment: I see, it didn't occur to me to define variables in the header like that (beyond a few . I was reading in a separate file and assigning it to `yaml`. That could still work potentially. We will see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see. I guess it shouldn't be a problem to use your approach instead with `include_graphics`, however the yaml parameters are exactly thought for this usecase